# Recover file damaged by vi when over quota?

Tags: linux, nfs, xfs

A user edited a file while he was over quota, and the new file could not be written back to disk.  He used vi.  The disk is on a NFS server which uses XFS.  CentOS 6 on the NFS server and CentOS 7 on the client.

His home directory was not over quota.  It was another disk.

Any way to retrieve the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user found the swap file and/or backup `~` file in his home directory.  I thought I looked there first, but I must have overlooked them before turning to ServerFault.

It's still a dangerous situation.  Users who exceed quotas are risking data loss, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The only way: Restore it from backup. No backup? No file.

Comment: Any details on how this happened?  I once knew, but have forgotten and couldn't find anything in Google.